# Count the number of nodes in binary tree on Prolog?

Tags: prolog, binary-tree

I have some code

```
tree1(tree(1,
            tree(2,
                tree(3,nil,nil),
                tree(4,nil,nil)),
            tree(5,
                tree(6,nil,nil),
                tree(7,nil,nil))
        )
    ).
rbt_count_nodes(e,0):-!.
rbt_count_nodes(t(_,L,R),N):-
    rbt_count_nodes(L,NL),
    rbt_count_nodes(R,NR),
    N=NL+NR+1.

?-tree1(T),rbt_count_nodes(T,N),write(N).
```

But goal always return No. Why ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
rbt_count_nodes(t(_,L,R),N)
```

should become

```
rbt_count_nodes(tree(_,L,R),N)
```

and

```
N=NL+NR+1
```

should become

```
N is NL + NR + 1
```

(`(=)/2` is used to perform unification, `(is)/2` to perform arithmetic).

and

```
rbt_count_nodes(e,0):-!.
```

should become

```
rbt_count_nodes(nil,0).
```

After those three edits it should be fine, though I cannot test so I might be proven wrong.

Comment: to this I could only add that Prolog data is symbolic and Prolog unification is structural unification of symbolic data; while `is` *forces* an argument expression under assumption that it describes an arithmetic entity. And you can always test at http://ideone.com . :)

Answer (score 4):

Beside the notes given in another answer (using `is/2` instead of `=/2` and the typos in the name of the terms t->tree and e->empty), you should consider using an accumulator to allow the prolog system to do tail recursion:

```
rbt_count_nodes(T,N):-
  rbt_count_nodes(T, 0, N).

rbt_count_nodes(nil,N, N):-!.
rbt_count_nodes(tree(_,L,R),C,N):-
    succ(C, C1),
    rbt_count_nodes(L,C1,NL),
    rbt_count_nodes(R,NL,N).
```

Procedure `rbt_count_nodes/2` just calls `rbt_count_nodes/3` with zero as the second argument (accumulator). Upon each recursion step, this accumulator gets incremented by one and does recursion. The base case just unifies the accumulator with your output allowing the system to do tail recursion and economize on stack space.

[edit]

As per comments, to make it truly tail recursive (that is, all recursive calls are tail calls) you can add a new clause to rbt_count_nodes/3 (and modify another):

```
rbt_count_nodes(nil,N, N):-!.
rbt_count_nodes(tree(Node,tree(LNode, LL, LR),R),C,N):-
  rbt_count_nodes(tree(Node, LL, tree(LNode, LR, R)), C, N).
rbt_count_nodes(tree(_,nil,R),C,N):-
  succ(C, C1),
  rbt_count_nodes(R,C1, N).
```

With this approach, the first clause deal with an empty node, the second one deals with the left side of the tree which just "moves" the branch to the right hand side of the current node, and the third clause just computes the count of nodes.

Comment: this code is not tail recursive. And you don't need the cut, as `nil` and `tree(_,_,_)` are mutually-exclusive choices.

Comment: @Will Ness: This code is tail recursive, why do you say otherwise ?. I just modified OP code, so I left the cut.

Comment: @Mog: You're right about the variable name. Changed that name!

Comment: It's not tail recursive because the predicate calls itself before the last instruction (even if the last instruction is a call to istelf too). That means that Prolog will have to save the context, unlike in a tail recursive approach.

Comment: I'd say it is technically tail recursive because upon last recursive call it will discard context. However you are right that the first recursive call to itself does need the retain context.

Comment: The last call is indeed a tail call; but not all recursive calls inside your procedure are tail calls, so it is not tail-recursive. To  make it tail-recursive you'll need to maintain a list of nodes to visit as an additional argument, push right child onto it and then tail-call into the left child. Upon hitting nil, you'd continue with the first node in that list, if any.

Comment: @Will Ness: We would have to settle in a definition of tail recursion. According to wikipedia (not that I'd say its the best place to see definitions), this procedure is indeed [tail recursive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_recursion). Citing wikipedia: "...a tail call is a subroutine call that happens inside another procedure **as its final action**... If a subroutine performs a tail call to itself, it is called tail-recursive. "

Comment: you're right, that definition is obviously incomplete. The function is tail-recursive if *all* its recursive calls are tail calls. According to same WP article, *"Tail calls are significant because they can be implemented without adding a new stack frame to the call stack."* That is what counts.